# What would be the steady state of x in following system X -k-> 2X, 2X -k*v(t)-> ∅ when v(t) = vo (const)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology, steady-state

I have a system of a mass action type.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  X @>{\text{$k$}}>> 2X,   2X @>{\text{$k\cdot v(t)$}}>> ∅
\end{CD}

When  $v(t) = v_0(const)$, what is the stable state of x, ${x^s}^t$?

I am thinking

$\frac{dx}{dt}$ = $kX - k*v(t) 2X = 0$.

Therefore, when $v(t) = v_0(const)$,
the steady state of x = $\frac{k}{k}$ = 1.

Is it correct? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I edited the question.

Comment: You have one steady state at $x = 0$.